# Thought experiment with specific heat

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, energy-conservation, thought-experiment

I have been thinking about the following thought experiment regarding a material whose specific heat decreases with external electric field (see [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/236874030_Dependence_of_specific_heat_on_electric_field_in_Ba_1-x_Ca_x_TiO_3_ferroelectric_perovskites) for an example of such a material). Say that we put such a material outside under no electric field and let it equilibriate to the ambient temperature of 300 K. We then bring over a parallel-plate capacitor that we have precharged which generates a strong electric field between the plates, and place the material inside of it. Now, because the specific heat capacity of the material has been lowered, it can no longer hold all the heat that it previously contained, and so it will radiate heat into the environment. In theory, one could use this heat transfer to power a heat engine or drive an electric power plant. Once equilibriated, we remove the material from the capacitor, and it will start to suck in heat from the air, which can once again be used to generate power - and in theory, it seems like this cycle can be repeated ad infinitum. Clearly, this can't be the case, because what I am describing is an infinite source of free power, but can anyone point out the flaw in my above argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now, because the specific heat capacity of the material has been lowered, it can no longer hold all the heat that it previously contained

Heat capacity tells us how much energy is needed to produce a change in temperature. It is not a measure of the total energy something can "hold". A change in heat capacity does not result in spontaneous energy absorption or emission "for free".

Comment: This seems to be the simplest and most correct answer to me. A change in heat capacity of a material has no impact on its current temperature. If it's sitting at 300K and happens to undergo a change in heat capacity, it will still be 300K but it may need more or less heat to change the temp.

Answer (score 2):

> Now, because the specific heat capacity of the material has been
> lowered, it can no longer hold all the heat that it previously
> contained, and so it will radiate heat into the environment.

Firstly, materials do not "contain" heat. Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. What a material contains is internal energy, which is the sum of its kinetic and potential energy at the microscopic level.

Secondly, placing the material in an electrostatic field will not cause it to "radiate heat into the environment" any more than it normally does due to its 300K temperature. In order to increase radiant heat from the material to the same environment the temperature of the material needs to increase. That will not happen by simply placing the material in the electrostatic field.

If, in fact, the electrostatic field does lower the specific heat capacity of the material, all that means is the increase/decrease in material temperature resulting from heat transferred to/from the material will be greater with the field than without the field.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "*In order to increase radiant heat from the material to the same environment the temperature of the material needs to increase. That will not happen by simply placing the material in the electrostatic field.*" Citation needed for the claim that $\partial T/\partial E$ (temperature $T$, electric field $E$) can never be positive for any material. I don't buy it, and this isn't where the scheme fails.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I don't understand your comment. Please explain further. Please note I am referring to an electrostatic field not an electromagnetic field.

Comment: A system is described as being inserted into an electric field; thus, $dE$ is positive. You write that $dT$ cannot be positive as this occurs (i.e., as electrical work is done on the system). This doesn't sound right to me (in particular, it implies that the pyroelectric coefficient of all materials must be zero), so I'd like to know the reasoning.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Sorry, never heard of "pyroelectric coefficient". I'll have to look it up and get back to you.

Comment: @Chemomechanics Is this what you're referring to ? " The pyroelectric coefficient describes the change in the electric charge per unit of surface area following a temperature change of one degree." (From: ScienceDirect  article on Pyroelectricitity)

Comment: Yes; that material property is coupled (through a Maxwell relation) to the temperature increase when a system is brought into an electric field.

Comment: So you're saying  a temperature change causing a change in the electric charge per unit of surface area means a change in electric charge per unit of surface area causes a change in temperature?

Comment: And is this something akin to dielectric heating?

Comment: The [electrocaloric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrocaloric_effect) is distinct from [dielectric heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dielectric_heating).

Comment: The article on the electrocaloric effect talks about a decrease not an increase in temperature due to the electric field. In any case,  what does this have to do with the effect of an electric field on the specific heat capacity?

Comment: [Some materials cool down, whereas others heat up.](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1209/0295-5075/102/47004/meta) As I wrote above (twice), your answer currently claims that no material heats up upon being placed in an electric field. What's the basis for the claim?

Comment: @Chemomechanics Mea Culpa, Mea Culpa, I was not aware of the phenomena. But is it really significant/relevant here? The OP is suggesting there will be heat loss due to the change in specific heat capacity due to the field. Is this "electrocaloric effect" responsible for a change in specific heat capacity?

Comment: Of course—we're all here to learn through discussing physics. I just don't think your resolution to the problem is a valid one, as one of the logical steps isn't supported by experiments. Perhaps the solution can be shored up by inserting a different logical step.

Answer (score 1):

Others have pointed out problems in your specific wording: Heat can't be "held," etc. So just replace

"Now, because the specific heat capacity of the material has been lowered, it can no longer hold all the heat that it previously contained, and so it will radiate heat into the environment."

with

"An electric field increases the material's temperature, which can be used to power a heat engine."

This seems to maintain the intended strategy, yes?

The problem is that it takes energy to polarize the material with the electric field—current will flow during the charging process—and you can't recover this energy entirely with a heat engine. You don't end up with net energy production but rather conservation of energy and net **entropy** production, which isn't useful.

Edit: See also the section “Electrocaloric Cooling: How Does it Work?” on p6 [here](http://ndl.ethernet.edu.et/bitstream/123456789/30285/1/5.pdf).